# How do I correctly store an (Objective-C) SKProduct* in a C++ std::map?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I have a `std::map<std::string, SKProduct*>` which I populate like this:

```
// Assume s_map is always accessed in a thread safe way    
static auto s_map = std::map<std::string, SKProduct*>{};

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
  auto map = std::map<std::string, SKProduct*>{};
  const auto product_id = std::string(
    [product.productIdentifier UTF8String]
  );
  for(SKProduct* product in response.products) {
    if(product != nil) {
      map[product_id] = product;
      [map[product_id] retain]; 
    }
  }
  s_map = map;
}
```

Later (when a purchase is made) I find the SKProduct* like this:

```
auto make_purchase(const product_id_t& product_id) -> void {
  // Note that the whole map is copied
  const std::map<std::string, SKProduct*> map = s_map;
  const auto product_it = map.find(product_id);
  if(it == map.end()) {
    return;
  }
  // Here somewhere I get a crash objc_retain_x0
  SKProduct* product = product_it->second;
  [product retain];
  SKPayment* payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct: product];
  [payment retain]; 
  // Continue the purchase from here on...
}
```

Am I doing something wrong when storing/retrieving the `SKProduct*` from the `std::map`? I'm not familiar with the Objective-C model of reference counting.

(Note that the code is a bit simplified for clarity compared to the original code)

Comment: Do you compile it without ARC enabled?

Comment: Also, could you please elaborate a little more how transition between `store_map(map)` and `get_map()` happens? Does it save to file / restore from file? Or is it stored in string and then restored? (i'm rather interested whether the same instances of `SKProduct *` are used in the `make_purchase` function

Comment: @TheDreamsWind The map is just stored as a variable (updated code to be more clear). I would like the code to function regardless of if ARC is enabled/disabled. Basically, I don't know when the SKProduct* in the map is destructed.

Comment: My `[product retain];` is just there to make sure it is not destructed. I don't know what I'm doing. Should for example it be `map[product_id] = product;` be `map[product_id] = [product retain];`

Comment: I'm doubtful you can make the code ARC-agnostic, because ARC forbids explicit messages to reference counting methods (`retain`/`release`/`autorelease`, etc..). Under MRC, however, this code has some excessive `retain`'s, but overall I can't spot any reason for it to crash. What exact error message do you get here and which line?

Comment: and yes - you can put `retain` inline, it should not make any difference

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash myself, I only get the crash callstacks (naming objc_retain_x0 at the top) from the crash reporter. But if I understand correctly, SKProduct* shouldn't at least be destructed under the hood, even due I have too many retains? (Note that ARC is disabled, but weak references in manual retain is enabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question in the title, I would encapsulate this part into a custom container class to wrap the memory management inside. Here is the minimalistic implementation example:

```objc
template<typename Key> // Key type must not be a retain-release object
class id_unordered_map {
    std::unordered_map<Key, id> m_underlying_map;

    void clear() {
        for (const auto& element: m_underlying_map) {
            [element.second release];
        }
        m_underlying_map.clear();
    }


public:
    id_unordered_map() = default;

    id_unordered_map(const id_unordered_map& rhs) {
        for (const auto& element: rhs.m_underlying_map) {
            // makes a shallow copy
            m_underlying_map[element.first] = [element.second retain];
        }
    };

    id_unordered_map(id_unordered_map&& rhs) {
        for (const auto& element: rhs.m_underlying_map) {
            m_underlying_map[element.first] = [element.second retain];
        }
        rhs.clear();
    }

    id_unordered_map& operator=(const id_unordered_map& rhs) {
        clear();
        for (const auto& element: rhs.m_underlying_map) {
            // makes a shallow copy
            m_underlying_map[element.first] = [element.second retain];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    id_unordered_map& operator=(id_unordered_map&& rhs) {
        clear();
        for (const auto& element: rhs.m_underlying_map) {
            m_underlying_map[element.first] = [element.second retain];
        }
        rhs.clear();
        return *this;
    }

    void setObject(const Key& key, id object) {
        removeObject(key);

        if (object) {
            m_underlying_map[key] = [object retain];
        }
    }

    id getObject(const Key& key) {
        if (auto it = m_underlying_map.find(key); it != m_underlying_map.end()) {
            return it->second;
        } else {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    void removeObject(const Key& key) {
        if (auto it = m_underlying_map.find(key); it != m_underlying_map.end()) {
            [it->second release];
            m_underlying_map.erase(it);
        }
    }

    ~id_unordered_map() {
        clear();
    }
};
```

I suggest a shallow copy approach here, as it's consistent with how Cocoa own collections work. Making a deep copy is considered an exceptional case and requires as separate method (e.g. [`initWithDictionary:copyItems:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1410124-initwithdictionary?language=objc) constructor of `NSDictionary`)

However personally I don't feel like there is an apparent mistake in the provided code which makes the app to crash. The error you are observing commonly happens when a message is sent to an object which is not set to `nil` but already released. And provided no `release` messages are sent to the objects in the map in between the functions, your `SKProduct` object has to survive.

Here are a few things to consider though:

- [productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequestdelegate/1506070-productsrequest?language=objc) invocation thread is unspecified, and it's 99% different from UI thread, where I assume your `make_purchase` function is called from. It means, that objects spawned in the delegate thread might go out of autorelease pool they were created in (this, however, should not be a problem provided you `retain`ed the objects and no race-condition happens when reading/writing to the map).
- `[SKPayment paymentWithProduct: product];` returns an autoreleased object, which won't expire (at least) until end of the current scope, so you are not required to `retain` it.
- If you make product requests multiple times during lifecycle of your app, ensure that you release the objects the map contains and `clear()` it before writing new data to the map.

---

Summing it up, your `SKProductsRequestDelegate` should looks something like this (the product here is artificial, so i make it on the fly in the response):

```objc
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TDWObject ()<SKProductsRequestDelegate>

@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t productsSyncQueue;
@property (assign, nonatomic) id_unordered_map<std::string> products;
@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) NSMutableSet<SKProductsRequest *> *pendingRequests;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

@implementation TDWObject

@synthesize products = _products;

#pragma mark Lifecycle

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _productsSyncQueue = dispatch_queue_create("the.dreams.wind.property_access.products",
                                                    DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
        _pendingRequests = [[NSMutableSet set] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_pendingRequests release];
    [_productsSyncQueue release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark Properties

- (id_unordered_map<std::string>)products {
    __block id_unordered_map<std::string> *data;
    dispatch_sync(_productsSyncQueue, ^{
        // Take by pointer here, to avoid redundant copy
        data = &_products;
    });
    return *data; // makes a copy for observers
}

- (void)setProducts:(id_unordered_map<std::string>)products {
    dispatch_barrier_async(_productsSyncQueue, ^{
        _products = std::move(products);
    });
}

#pragma mark Actions

- (void)requestProducts {
    SKProductsRequest *productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:@[
        @"the.dreams.wind.sampleSKU1"
    ]]];
    productRequest.delegate = self;
    [productRequest start];
    [_pendingRequests addObject:productRequest];
}

- (void)makePurchase {
    SKProduct *product = [_products.getObject("the.dreams.wind.sampleSKU1") retain];
    // Just checking that the object exists
    NSLog(@"%@", product);
    [product release];
}

#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    [_pendingRequests removeObject:request];

    decltype(_products) newProducts;
    // Artificial Products
    for (NSString *identifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers) {
        newProducts.setObject(identifier.UTF8String, [[SKProduct new] autorelease]);
    }
    self.products = newProducts;

}
```

You can see here that access/reading of the map is synchronised with use of GCD and Objective-C properties, which, I admit, is horribly ineffective when it comes to C++ objects accessed by value. You will want to optimise it BUT it should work without crashes I believe.

**P.S.** you usually also want to synchronise reading from/writing to `pendingRequests` set, but it's not relevant in context of the question, thus I omitted this part.

---

You may also consider just taking the products arrays by reference, without employing C++ objects, which should work just fine and is much more straightforward:

```objc
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    [_pendingRequests removeObject:request];
    NSArray<SKProduct *> *products = [response.products retain];
    ...
}
```

Comment: A big thank you, will implement. Also, a good idea to simply keep the whole array. Also, I'm thinking about instead of wrapping the whole map, I can simply make a class which wraps an Objective-C object (and does the retain/release inside the copy-constructor etc)